# Invalid command name "tk_chooseDirectory" error

Tags: r, bioconductor, genome, tcltk

I am using bioconductor for WES pipeline and I am using tk_choose.dir for selection of directory (and store it for further use) where user has stored input files. Here the command lines

```
library(tcltk)
dataDir <- dirname(tk_choose.dir(default = " ", caption = "Select Directory for input fastq files"))
```

But these command lines shows some error, shown below (although  **library(tcltk)** is working fine)

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
[tcl] invalid command name "tk_chooseDirectory".
```

Any hint guys, I am not able to figure out if library is already installed and loaded then why this command is not working. I am using R version 3.4.3 and bioconductor version 3.2

Thanks.